# Query no se ejecuta en Rails: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo la siguiente query que no se ejecuta en RoR. Más abajo pongo el error que me da al querer ejecutarla. No sé cómo pasarle los parámetros para que tampoco sea vulnerable.

```
$consumo_grp = FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("SELECT AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.AFILIADO, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.EMITIDO, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.CANTIDAD, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.PRACTICA, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.SUBTOTAL_ASPURC, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.SUBTOTAL_AFILIADO FROM AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP
  (?, ?, ? ", "#{current_user.affiliate.id_persona}", "#{1.month.ago.to_date.at_beginning_of_month}", "#{1.month.ago.to_date.end_of_month})")
```

Error que me arroja al ejecutar la query:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..2)
```

Comment: y as probado si ambos metodos son `vulnerables` ? porque no intentas mejor utilizar los metodos por defecto que tiene `ror` para busquedas dentro de la base de datos! [querys](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Lo que pasa que esto es un procedimiento que se ejecuta en una base de datos de Firebird que es distinta a la que utilizo en RoR ya que es un sistema paralelo realizado en Delphi y necesito ejecutar procesos de esa base de datos

Comment: la base de datos no tiene nada que ver con el saneado de `ror` ya que esto lo que fuerza es a escapar posibles caracteres que vulneren la base de datos, por otro lado recomiendo agregar  params() ejemplo: `#{params[:current_user.affiliate.id_persona]}`

Comment: Probe con lo que me pasaste pero tampoco me anduvo

Comment: ok, vamos a ver si comprendo tu problema... 1. la query no se ejecuta? o que tienes algun error de sql injection? si quieres probar la seguridad del mismo puedes usar la herramienta [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/) en caso de ser la primera debes editar la pregunta

Comment: Si, efectivamente la query no se ejecuta ahi la edito

Comment: vale perfecto intenta agregar todo el codigo que este relacionado incluyendo la conexion a la base de datos, nota: evita incluir password y nombres de base de datos... o remplazalos por la palabra `test` es solo para saber que metodo utilizas!

Comment: Alli edite la pregunta completa para que veas si podes darte cuenta del error que tengo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: yo no se ruby.. pero esa query esta mal formada en cualquier lenguaje.. le faltan comas, no se si los tres strings con # son los parametros, pero si es asi, al query le faltan parentesis de cierre... si podes, fijate cual es la cadena resultante como query  y vas a ver que falla...

Comment: $consumo_grp = FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("SELECT AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.AFILIADO, 
        AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.EMITIDO, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.CANTIDAD, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.PRACTICA, 
        AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.SUBTOTAL_ASPURC, AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.SUBTOTAL_AFILIADO 
        FROM AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP
      (?, ?, ? )", current_user.affiliate.id_persona, 
      1.month.ago.to_date.at_beginning_of_month, 
      1.month.ago.to_date.end_of_month)

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que piensas es sanitizar parámetros, `execute` no lo permite directamente, así que tendrías que hacerlo de antemano llamando a [`sanitize_sql`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.7/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql) antes de ejecutar la query:

```
class FirebirdDBModel
  # La consulta debe ir dentro del modelo, ya que sanitize_sql es un método de
  # tipo protected, por lo tanto no podrías llamarlo desde el controlador con
  # FirebirdDBModel.sanitize_sql
  def self.tu_consulta(id)
    # Esta fecha no depende del controlador, así que puede ser perfectamente
    # definida dentro del modelo
    fecha = 1.month.ago.to_date
    query = sanitize_sql [
      # Esto es un string de tipo heredoc, que soporta multilinea. El squish
      # simplemente te concatena cada línea en una única y borra los espacios
      # sobrantes en los alrededores
      <<-SQL.squish, id, fecha.at_beginning_of_month, fecha.end_of_month
        SELECT
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.AFILIADO,
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.EMITIDO,
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.CANTIDAD,
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.PRACTICA,
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.SUBTOTAL_ASPURC,
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP.SUBTOTAL_AFILIADO
        FROM
          AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP
        WHERE
          tu_parametro_1 = ?
          AND tu_parametro_2 = ?
          AND tu_parametro_3 = ?
        SQL
      ]
    connection.execute(query)
  end  
end
```

Y si, agregué esas columnas `tu_parametro_x` en la consulta, ya que como mencionan en los comentarios, tu sentencia SQL está incorrecta. Estás pasando los parámetros `current_user.affiliate.id_persona, 1.month.ago.to_date.at_beginning_of_month, 1.month.ago.to_date.end_of_month` a tu consulta, sin embargo no veo que estén dentro de un `WHERE` o cualquier otra cláusula SQL que acepte parámetros. Así tal cual está la consulta, vas a retornar TODOS los registros de la tabla `AFILIADOS_CONSUMO_GRP`.
Luego que hayas definido qué hacer con los parámetros en la query, la llamas con:

```
$consumo_grp = FirebirdDBModel.tu_consulta(current_user.affiliate.id_persona)
```